# Meaning of 「さいってー」 as an interjection

Tags: meaning, interjections

What is the meaning of 「さいってー」 in the following dialogue?

[image]

Context: before this scene, the character on the left has just explained to his accomplice on the right why he decided to betray and kill some of their friends, the scene ends after the dialogue above. I know that さ means something like "well" when used alone, but I've never heard of さいってー. Is it a synonym of さて?. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe that it's a form of 最{さい}低{てい} - the lowest. Which means something along the lines of 'that sucks' or 'you suck'

Comment: Not a "form" in terms of written form, it's just that the speaker is emphasizing it in their speech. Just like we would say in English "Sooooooooo bad!!!" This is attempting to recreate that nuance in their speech.

Answer (score 3):

It　definitely means 最低, pronounced さいてい. Writing it this way emphasis on the slang way of speaking of the character, especially with the っ.
The author could have written it 最低, which is the proper way of writing it this word, but it would have less power. Remember as well that in Japanese the えい is exactly pronounced the same way as えー.